# Make Windows Service run a specific file

Tags: c#, windows, service, windows-services, installation

I've been watching some tuts on how to create a C# Windows Service; all good but no one says how to make te service run, at the end of installation, a specific file from installation folder(in my case hidden.vbs)(my app has 2 project: the service itself and the setup).
After the install of the setup, the service starts PROJECT_NAME.exe and PROJECT_NAME.svhost.exe

Tell me please if you need any other code in order to help me...
Here is my Program.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;


namespace PROJECT_NAME
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {
            new ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName).Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Service1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;

namespace PROJECT_NAME
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void OnDebug()
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStart.txt");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStart.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, here is a pic of my Solution Explorer https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbHgF.png ; please tell me how or where should I import the files I need the service to run.

It's my first time in C#, I'm not willing to understand it now, but to make this service because I will need it in my work..

Answer (score 0):

Your script can do one of several things to start a service:

- Issue the `net start` console command to launch a service (e.g. `net start "My Service Name"`)

OR

- Programmaticaly, call the [StartService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.

Comment: I think I wan't clear enough... The service starts automatically because of an event (AfterInstall) that I called. The problem is the application that the service starts, which is PROJECT_NAME.exe and PROJECT_NAME.svhost.exe. If it can't be changed(which I don't think so) at least tell me where to edit the PROJECT_NAME.exe so it will at least have included the hidden.vbs that I want to start.